# How do I to use the shift operator on a "binary string"?

Tags: java, binary, bit-shift

So far I have a binary number stored as a string:

```
String value = "111111110000000010101010";
```

and I want to use the shift operators so that it will then be equal to `000000000000000011111111`.

I know that I need to shift it 16 spots over but how do I convert the string value so that I can use the shift operator on it?

Comment: Is your question "how can I convert a binary string to a number?"?

Comment: Why use the shift operator rather than String operations?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Integer.parseInt(String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) to convert a String representing binary data to an int:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("111111110000000010101010", 2);
```

You can then shift using the [bit shift operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left, and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use [Java 7's binary literal notation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html), to avoid the problem in the first place...

```
int value = 0b111111110000000010101010;
int shifted = value >> 16;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(shifted)); 
=> 11111111
```